# Redirect without changing the url

Tags: cakephp, redirect, cakephp-2.0

How can I do a redirect without changing the url?

I currently use this:

```
$this->redirect('/Lojas/index');
```

or this:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Servicos', 'action' => 'index'));
```

But with these two forms the url changes. I need it to continue the same as before the redirect.

Anyone have any idea how to solve?

Comment: what is the url before?

Comment: something like: localhost/cakephp-2.3.0/StoreName

Comment: that's strange. you want to redirect keeping the same URL then is it really called redirect???
do you want to call any function or process anything?? then AJAX might help you. Please describe a little more to get help.

Comment: for example in the url I used above, where it says, storeName, will be the name of any one store.
The redirect will load a page totally different or is an more personalized page, of the store in question. So I want the url, keep the store name, not the name of the controller to which I am sending the request.

Comment: custom route dont help you? http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got retrieving a session variable in the file routes, and using this variable as "name" in the url.

```
    App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
       $sessao = CakeSession::read('loja');

Router::connect( "/".$sessao['storeName'], array('controller' => 'Lojas', 'action' => 'index'));
```